# Rails 4 querying code convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Fast Simple Example,

Have a Users table like this,

```
id : integer
name : varchar(255)
```

and have some seeds
1, john doe
2, john smith
...

ok, so i'm querying now.

if i want to get the second row with id.

what is the recommended way?

I know there are plenty of rails code convention

```
User.find(2)
User.find_by(:id => 2)
User.find_by_id(2)
User.where(:id => 2)
```

and more more...

what is the best recommended way?

our team is using all of the code convention.

I want to choose only one and integrate these codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You want a single model or nil:**
`User.find_by_id(2)`
**You want a single model or nil, and you might query more later:**
`User.find_by(:id => 2)`
`User.find_by(:id => 2, :email => 'user@email.com')`
**You want a single model or an exception, and you might query more later:**
`User.find_by!(:id => 2)`
`User.find_by!(:id => 2, :email => 'user@email.com')`
**You want a single model or an exception:**
`User.find(2)`
`User.find_by_id!(2)`
One is short, and one is explicit.  Your choice.
**You want an ActiveRecord Relation (multiple models) and to chain methods:**
`User.where(:name => 'Yoda').order('created_on DESC').find(2)`
In case lots of Yodas are lurking about.

Sources:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record

Comment: There is only **one** Yoda so the last query won't work!

Comment: @Vucko This is the Yoda you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If **id** is a primary key, The best way is

```
User.find(id)
```

And If **id** is not a primary one, I recommend you to use

```
User.find_by_id(id)
```

Always remember, **find** returns a single record, whereas **where** returns all matching records as an array.

Comment: what about in other condition? what if i have to find with name? what i'm unsatiesfied is some codes are using .find and some codes are using .where

Comment: I heard that find_by_something series are depreceated after rails 4

Comment: Am using rails 4, Still am using find_by_something :)

Comment: @Canna The above find is not deprecated. You can see the deprecated find methods here https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the use case,

The only thing to to note is:

```
User.find(id)
```

would raise an `Exception` if it doesn't find a record, whereas

```
User.find_by(id: 1)
```

would simply return nil, If you are handling `nil` s in your application then you needn't worry about it.

As per deprecation look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

And also that find() doesnot expect a `number`, what is expects is that the value you pass must have its 0'th character as number, so

```
User.find("1-this-works")
```

will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer hits the point - those are not conventions, they are functionally different approaches.

However, some of those expressions are functionally the same - Ruby is designed to allow different ways of expressing the same thing - it is because Ruby is a human-oriented language ([Ruby philosophy](http://www.artima.com/intv/ruby.html)) which means that it's creator adopted a human-linguistic idea that synonyms enhance our ability to understand the language by provoking helpful associations, when used correctly and don't really hurt when not used correctly (an idea often attributed to the creator of Perl - Larry Wall - see [There Is More Than One Way To Do It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) principle).

Bottom line is - this is one of the basic design principles of the Ruby language - it's generally a good idea to embrace the philosophy of the language that you (assumably?) recently adopted rather than force habits from previous languages onto the new one